# Prevent Googlebot from crawling "access denied" error (403) of private forum that are reported in Google Search Console?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, forum, 403-forbidden

I'm running a website base it by vbulletin. Recently I moved one of my forums to a private section of my website so users and googlebot cannot access it there.

Now I'm getting lots of access denied errors in my Google Webmaster Tools.
How can I tell to googlebot to do not crawl that special forum and associated topics?

Comment: I'm assuming you submit sitemaps to google when you try to index your site. If you do, consider removing URLs that aren't accessible by everyone and resubmit and let google take its sweet time in reindexing your site.

Comment: Thanks, I did it before but I received the same (403) errors in webmaster again

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a robots `noindex` directive for the private section of the site, or a robots `noindex` meta tag to said pages.